# SIFT descriptors values: OpenCV vs VLFeat

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I'm trying to compare the SIFT implementation of [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) and [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html).

I noticed that the descriptors value for VLFeat are integers, such as:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 45 20 26 0 1 ...`

While for OpenCV:

`0.0391555 0 0 0.0998274 0.235747 0 0 0.0276871 0.156622 ...`

Notice that these are descriptors for 2 different images.

I have two questions:

1. Why they have two different values?
2. If I'm going to need the OpenCV representation for k-means using VLFeat (and then VLAD encoding) do I need to change these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm not an expert in OpenCV or VLFeat but I think that I know answers.

VLFeat can generate both integer and float descriptors. To generate integer descriptors use [vl_sift](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html) function and in order to generate float descriptors use [vl_dsift](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html) function with *FloatDescriptors* parameter.

VLFeat probably uses integer descriptors for performance reasons. Calculations using integers are generally faster than using floats. However, it could be at the expense of precision. Nonetheless, in the case of the computer vision a smaller precision may not be so crucial. In the description of the [integer k-means algorithm](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/ikm.html) you can even read "While this is limiting for some application, it works well for clustering image descriptors, where very high precision is usually unnecessary".

As to k-means algorithm. There is a version ([vl_ikmeans](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_kmeans.html)) for integers descriptors and the version ([vl_kmeans](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_ikmeans.html))] for float descriptors. With OpenCV simply use the latter.

Comment: `vl_sift`and `vl_dsift` are *totally* different algorithms w.r.t. the procedure to generate keypoints, they cannot be compared based on the descriptors values (int or float).

Comment: According to the VLFeat [documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html): "By default, VL_DSIFT() computes features equivalent to VL_SIFT()". There is also an example described as "This example produces equivalent SIFT descriptors using VL_DSIFT() and VL_SIFT():"

Comment: My fault, I didn't know that the default behavior was the same (I removed the -1 ;) ). However, DSIFT means "Dense SIFT" and the keypoints are generated from a standard grid. Maybe you can obtain the same behavior, but the purpose of the two algorithms are different.

Comment: For example DSIFT is widely used in classification, while SIFT is better for object recognition. But this is OT.

Comment: Anyway, according to me VLFeat uses integers because of performance reasons. However, you should be able to use vl_kmeans, which works with floats, with OpenCV descriptors.